# How to build website with two speaking language (Arabic and English)?

Tags: asp-classic, localization

I am beginner in web designing, I using CLASSIC ASP for web development.
My client need his website in two languages (Arabic and English).

What is the best way for develop website in multiple language?

I read some information from website's :-

1. Create website in two lanuages. for example (www.example.com/English/)and (www.example.com/Arabic/)

2.Use transilaters(Google,SpeakFish,etc..) for your default website.

Anyone can help me for this which is the suitable way for develop website in multiple languages?

Any reference or any links?

hoping your help

Comment: Uh-oh! Do you _really_ want to begin your webdev experience with classic ASP?

Comment: @Alex: Please don't post the same question twice. If you have something to add, click the [edit] link on your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500938/how-to-build-multi-language-website-english-and-arabic

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods:

- your first method - create two different sites - has as advantage that the texts can be custom tailored for each language
- create a single site, but display every text with a function that knows the current language and shows the text in one or the other - will be easier to update, but a little harder to change all translations

I would say don't use automatic translators - they do a lousy job. Better let a human do this.

Comment: Agree especially with the human translations > online ones :)

Answer (score 1):

Build a single website using a CMS that does multilanguage out of the box, or supports plugins for multilingual sites (F.A. Joomla + JoomFish).

Online translators always create a really terrible reading experience, so please get a (possibly trained) human translator to covert the texts for you.